# manipulate two array of objects make new array and update the attribute of object1 and add in the new array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to compare two array of objects and want to achieve the custom array of object by manipulating it.

I would like to achieve something like this by checking each time anything from object1 is removed or not? if it is removed then it should change attribute to 'Y'.

```
object 1 = [
   {
      "label":"a",
      "removed":"N",
      "value":1
   },
   {
      "label":"b",
      "removed":"N",
      "value":2
   }
]

object 2 =[
   {
      "label":"a",
      "removed":"N",
      "value":1
   },
   {
      "label":"c",
      "removed":"N",
      "value":3
   }
]
```

result should be =

```
[{
label:"a",
removed:"N",
value:1
},{
label:"b",
removed:"Y",
value:2
},{
label:"c",
removed:"N",
value:3
}]
```

I have tried to loop both array and tried to achieve the same but it is somehow not working.

I tried following code.

```js
let data = []

object1.forEach((item1) => {

            object2.forEach((item2) => {

                    if (item1.value === item2.value) {
                        data.push(Object.assign(item1));
                    } else {
                        item2.removeFlag = 'Y';
                        data.push(Object.assign(item1, item2));

                    }
                }

            }
```

...Updated Question.....

```js
obj1 = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":26
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":128,
      "label":"type4-label2"
   }
]

obj2 = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-c",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-d",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":null,
      "id":null,
      "label":"type4-label3"
   }
]

result = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"Y",
            "dataid":26
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-c",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-d",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type2",
      "removed":"Y",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"Y",
      "id":128,
      "label":"type4-label2"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":null,
      "id":null,
      "label":"type4-label3"
   }
]
```

Comment: You want the result array to contain the values that have the same 'label' in both arrays, but also the object in array 1  that is not is array 2 with the `removed` field changed to 'Y'. Please explain what am I missing if this not the result you want.

Comment: yes exactly, I am looking for the result array which will track object1 and if the object1 is missing in object2 it will add and change the change removed field to 'Y'. It is basically tracking if something is removed from the object1.

Comment: You want to check the equality by the field 'label' right?

Comment: by value or label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const object1 = [{
    "label": "a",
    "removed": "N",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "b",
    "removed": "N",
    "value": 2
  }
]

const object2 = [{
    "label": "a",
    "removed": "N",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "c",
    "removed": "N",
    "value": 3
  }
]

const result = [...object2.map(record => {
  const record2 = object1.find(pr => pr.label === record.label) || {};

  return {
    ...record,
    ...record2
  }
}), ...object1.filter(pr => !object2.some(npr => npr.label === pr.label)).map(pr => ({ ...pr,
  removed: "Y"
}))]

console.log(result);
```

--Edit

With nested data you have to repeat the same code inside `reduce` function.

**Example**

```js
const result = [...object2.map(record => {
  const record2 = object1.find(pr => pr.val === record.val) || {};

  const data = [...(record.data || []).map(pr => ({ ...pr,
      ...(record2.data.find(npr => npr.label === pr.label) || {})
    })),
    ...(record2.data || []).filter(pr => !record.data.some(npr => npr.label === pr.label)).map(pr => ({ ...pr,
      removed: 'Y'
    }))
  ]

  return {
    ...record,
    ...record2,
    data

  }
}), ...object1.filter(pr => !object2.some(npr => npr.val === pr.val)).map(pr => ({ ...pr,
  removed: "Y"
}))]
```

Comment: thanks Jozef, I have one question in regards to nested array of objects, can we use same compare method or we need to iterate differently.

Comment: object 1 = [
   {
      "val":"val1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"a",
            "removed":"N",
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "label":"b",
            "removed":"N",
            "value":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"val2",
      "removed":"N"
   },
   {
      "val":"val3",
      "removed":"N"
   }
]

Comment: object 2 = [
   {
      "val":"val1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"a",
            "removed":"N",
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "label":"c",
            "removed":"N",
            "value":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"val2",
      "removed":"N"
   },
   {
      "val":"val4",
      "removed":"N"
   }
]

Comment: result = [
   {
      "val":"val1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"a",
            "removed":"N",
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "label":"c",
            "removed":"N",
            "value":3
         },
         {
            "label":"b",
            "removed":"Y",
            "value":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"val2",
      "removed":"N"
   },
   {
      "val":"val3",
      "removed":"Y"
   },
   {
      "val":"val4",
      "removed":"N"
   }
]

Comment: How I can achieve this?

Comment: Updated answer. There will be just more logic in `reduce` function

Comment: Thanks for the all answers... i got one question if i want to filter some object using val property and some using the id... is it possible? i would like to compare type1 and type2 based on val while type3/type4 based on id.. i updated question.please guide me

Comment: I think it would be much better to start a new question

Comment: sure. posted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045870/filter-and-map-the-property-of-the-array-of-objects-based-on-different-parameter

Comment: please check above link.  @Józef Podlecki

Comment: Can you please help me here in similar function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707256/manipulate-two-array-of-objects-make-new-array-and-update-the-attribute-of-objec