# filter and map the property of the array of objects based on different parameters in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to achieve the following by filtering and mapping the two array of nested objects using the map and filter in the angular.

I have got one solution in regards to my last question to filter based on specific property.

[manipulate two array of objects make new array and update the attribute of object1 and add in the new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943366/manipulate-two-array-of-objects-make-new-array-and-update-the-attribute-of-objec)

but I am not sure how to filter different objects based on different properties.

I want to filter some object using id property and some using the val... is it possible?

- i would like to compare type1 and type2 based on val
- i would like to compare type1 and type2 data object using dataid
- i would like to compare type3/type4 based on id..

```js
const obj1 = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":1,
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":26
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":2,
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":128,
      "label":"type4-label2"
   }
]

const obj2 = [
   {
      "val":"type1new",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":1
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1new",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-c",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-d",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":null,
      "id":128,
      "label":"new"
   }
]


result = [
   {
      "val":"type1new",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":1,
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1new",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"Y",
            "dataid":26
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-c",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-d",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type2",
      "removed":"Y",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"Y",
      "id":128,
      "label":"type4-label2"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":null,
      "id":null,
      "label":"type4-label3"
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":null,
      "id":128,
      "label":"new"
   }
]
```

---updated question above---

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would tackle it

```js
const obj1 = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":26
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type2",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type2-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":12
         },
         {
            "label":"type2-b",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":34
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":128,
      "label":"type4-label2"
   }
]

const obj2 = [
   {
      "val":"type1",
      "removed":"N",
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"type1-a",
            "removed":"N",
            "dataid":16
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-c",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         },
         {
            "label":"type1-d",
            "removed":null,
            "dataid":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":124,
      "label":"type3-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type4",
      "removed":"N",
      "id":126,
      "label":"type4-label1"
   },
   {
      "val":"type3",
      "removed":null,
      "id":128,
      "label":"new"
   }
]


const getIdentity = (obj) => {
  if(["type1", "type2"].includes(obj.val)) {
    return obj.val;
  }

  if(["type3", "type4"].includes(obj.val)) {
    return obj.id + obj.val;
  }
}

const result = obj1.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  const similarObj = obj2.find(nobj => getIdentity(nobj) === getIdentity(obj));
  
  if(["type1", "type2"].includes(obj.val) && similarObj) {
    const data = obj.data.reduce((nacc, item) => {
      
      const similarItem = similarObj.data.find(pr => pr.dataid === item.dataid);
      
      if(!similarItem) {

        return [...nacc, {...item, removed: 'Y'}];
      }
      
      const newItem = {
        ...item,
        ...similarItem
      }
      
      return [...nacc, newItem];
    }, similarObj.data.filter(pr => !obj.data.some(npr => pr.dataid === npr.dataid)))
    
    const newObj = {
      ...obj,
      ...similarObj,
      data
    }
    
    return [...acc, newObj];
  }
  
  if(!similarObj) {
    acc = [...acc, {
      ...obj,
      removed: "Y"
    }];
    
    return acc;
  }
  
  return [...acc, obj];

}, obj2.filter(obj => !obj1.some(nobj => getIdentity(obj) === getIdentity(nobj))))

result.sort((prev, next) => prev.val > next.val ? 1 : -1);

console.log(result);
```

Ideally every object would contain its unique `id` and `type` which decides if there should be additional processing. Thats my thought.

Comment: thanks for all answers... it works on all conditions except when object2 updates val in the object1 existing id  to this {"val":"type3","removed":null, "id":128, "label":"new label"}... result is not updating with the { "val":"type4", "removed":"Y", "id":128,"label":"type4-label2"}

Comment: updated question above.. where obj1 object which have unique id got update by obj2..in that scenario the removed="Y" is not coming.

Comment: @ Józef Podlecki, Can you help here?

Comment: The rule was to compare objects by `id` when they are of type `type3`,`type4`. Now it is not the case?

Comment: it is same case but what if someone override id ? in that case I want to get the older object as removed="Y"

Comment: I modified the function which gets identity from the object `return obj.id + obj.val;`. It seems to handle mentioned case but I am not sure about the other ones

Comment: Thanks a lot.. now I am having the unique id for all the types.

Comment: what changes  i need to do in code which will always check uniqueness with id+val for any types?

Comment: You have to change `getIdentity` function as it checks what's inside `val` property. I am not sure about `reduce` implementation.